# stage==null in .fla file when testing on web browser

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Im having a terrible issue with flash and started happening last night, If I create a file in Flash CS5.5 and add this code in the first frame:

trace(stage);

when I test it inside the Flash IDE it traces this:
[object Stage]

but when I run that same swf file in a web browser, it traces this:
null

its seems like it never adds the application to stage, why is this hapening? it has never happened me before, am I the onlyone?

Comment: btw, I also tried compiling a new file with Flash CS4 and same problem, I believe is someting with some stupid flashPlayer update

Comment: Have you tried listening to "Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE"? It should be dispatched around the same time the "stage" attribute is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its been a while since I've checked this post. Just to answer this question, it was just a player bug that got fixed in a later release.

Answer (score 1):

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddToStage);
private function onAddToStage(e:Event){
    trace(stage);
}
```

If the trace is never called, what is your browser and what is your flash player version?

Comment: never mind, this was some issue fixed on some earlier version. thx!